# Как переходить между виджетами pyqt5. Передача информации из первого скрытого виджета в другой показуемый

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Помогите реализовать.
Есть главное окно, на котором студент должен будет вбивать ФИО, группу и номер по списку.

Как мне передавать `номер по списку` в следующий виджет, после нажатия на кнопку "***Далее***"(зеленая кнопка)? и как возвращаться обратно к первому виджету при нажатии кнопки "***Назад***"(зеленая кнопка).

И вообще правильно ли я делаю, что скрываю центральный виджет, может есть какая-то более корректная альтернатива?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from first_try import Ui_MainWindow
from second_try import Ui_Form
import sys

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.setText('Назад')
        self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")


class Start_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Start_Window, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Лабораторная работа №1')

        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setPlaceholderText('Введите группу: ТФ-ХХ-ХХ')
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setMaxLength(9)

        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText('Введите ФИО:')
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")

        self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")

        self.ui.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")

        self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")
        self.ui.pushButton.setToolTip('<b>Продолжить<b>')

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide_widget)

    def hide_widget(self):
        # self.ui.lineEdit_6.setText(self.ui.comboBox.currentText())
        self.ui.centralwidget.hide()
        self.setCentralWidget(Widget())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = Start_Window()
application.show()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**first_try**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(938, 514)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.comboBox.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit_6.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ЛАБОРАТОРНАЯ РАБОТА №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите номер варианта по списку"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "12"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("MainWindow", "13"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(13, _translate("MainWindow", "14"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(14, _translate("MainWindow", "15"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(15, _translate("MainWindow", "16"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(16, _translate("MainWindow", "17"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(17, _translate("MainWindow", "18"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(18, _translate("MainWindow", "19"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(19, _translate("MainWindow", "20"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(20, _translate("MainWindow", "21"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(21, _translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(22, _translate("MainWindow", "23"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(23, _translate("MainWindow", "24"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(24, _translate("MainWindow", "25"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(25, _translate("MainWindow", "26"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(26, _translate("MainWindow", "27"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(27, _translate("MainWindow", "28"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(28, _translate("MainWindow", "29"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(29, _translate("MainWindow", "30"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(30, _translate("MainWindow", "31"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(31, _translate("MainWindow", "32"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(32, _translate("MainWindow", "33"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(33, _translate("MainWindow", "34"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(34, _translate("MainWindow", "35"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Далее"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
```

**second_try**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(560, 473)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста модули `first_try.py` и `second_try.py`

Comment: Да, извините, все опубликовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда публикуйте все необходимые модули для воспроизведения вашего приложения.

Вариант того что вы хотите сделать, может выглядеть так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from first_try import Ui_MainWindow
from second_try import Ui_Form


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.label.setText(f'{self.label.text()} <b style="color: red;">{text}</b>') 

        self.pushButton.setText('Назад')
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_second)
        
    def on_button_second(self):
        self.parent.show()
        self.hide()


class Start_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Start_Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Лабораторная работа №1')

        self.lineEditGrup.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")
        self.lineEditGrup.setMaxLength(9)
        self.lineEditFio.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setToolTip('<b>Продолжить<b>')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide_widget)

    def hide_widget(self):
        self.widget = Widget(self.comboBox.currentText(), self)
        self.widget.show()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    application = Start_Window()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**first_try.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(675, 482)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(240, 300))
        self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(240, 300))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.labelTitle = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelTitle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.labelTitle.setFont(font)
        self.labelTitle.setObjectName("labelTitle")
        self.lineEditGrup = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEditGrup.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 171, 20))
        self.lineEditGrup.setObjectName("lineEditGrup")
        self.lineEditFio = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEditFio.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 171, 20))
        self.lineEditFio.setObjectName("lineEditFio")
        self.labelCombo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelCombo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(16, 150, 211, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.labelCombo.setFont(font)
        self.labelCombo.setObjectName("labelCombo")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(38, 180, 161, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 220, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 675, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.labelTitle.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Лабораторная работа № 1"))
        self.lineEditGrup.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите группу: ТФ-ХХ-ХХ"))
        self.lineEditFio.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ФИО:"))
        self.labelCombo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите номер варианта по списку"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "21"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "21"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Далее"))
```

**second_try.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(675, 391)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 311, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "здесь должно быть написано:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> хотел бы узнать можно ли как-нибудь открывать второй виджет не в отдельном окне, как у вас, а в этом же окне программы (просто скрывая основной и показывая другой, и наоборот)?

Все можно, но другой вопрос насколько это нужно. Обратите внимание, что в этом примере используются приведенные ваши модули first_try.py и second_try.py.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from first_try import Ui_MainWindow
from second_try import Ui_Form


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)                       # + parent
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.textEdit.setText(text)         

        self.pushButton.setText('Назад')
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_second)
        
    def on_button_second(self):
        self.close()                                                # +
        self.parent.frame.show()                                    # +


class Start_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Start_Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Лабораторная работа №1')

        self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")
        self.lineEdit_6.setPlaceholderText('Введите группу: ТФ-ХХ-ХХ')
        self.lineEdit_6.setMaxLength(9)

        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText('Введите ФИО:')
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"HouschkaRoundedAlt 9\";")
# ???        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);") # ???

        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setToolTip('<b>Продолжить<b>')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide_widget)
        
    def hide_widget(self):
        self.widget = Widget(self.comboBox.currentText(), self)
        self.frame.hide()                                                     # +
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget)                          # +


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    application = Start_Window()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо огромное за ответ, да, это то, что мне нужно, но хотел бы узнать можно ли как-нибудь открывать второй виджет не в отдельном окне, как у вас, а в этом же окне программы (просто скрывая основной и показывая другой, и наоборот)?

Comment: @ShalunZaharov  я добавил второй вариант, проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, это то, что нужно было!